# Alert box closing when user touches blank screen in Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am getting one simple problem,  I have tried to find solution in google but did not get any solution because search keyword I think so. I am displaying alert box through javascript  but its get closing automatically when user touches blank(Outside the alert window) screen I mean without user interaction also its closing. 
Its not closing in **Android 2.2 version**. Its closing only on higher version. What might be the problem? Please any faced this problem?

Below code is touch event for small image.
alert box is prompt on the center of screen BUT get closes when user touchs outside the alert box window

```
$('#bombImg').on('touchstart',function(touchEvent) {
        sound = new Media("/android_asset/www/beep2.mp3");
        sound.play();
        document.getElementById('resetBtn').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('trns').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('bombImg').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cityImg').style.position = 'absolute';
        document.getElementById('bomb').style.display = "block";
        enableZoomButtons();
        window.alert("Bomb defused");
        touchEvent.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is my Java code

```
 public class Adventure extends DroidGap {
@SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "NewApi" })
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.logo);
    // super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    //super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Loading..");
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
    super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this,
            appView, this), "MyAndroid");
    appView.setOnClickListener(null);
    WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings();
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
    appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // appView.loadUrl("javascript:getValue()");
}    
}
```

Please anybody answer this

Comment: Post the code which you have tried.

Comment: Did you try `alert()` instead of `window.alert()` ?

Comment: @Aishvarya Yes actually I was trying alert only after searching I edited window BUT no luck

Comment: seems like it should be a bug or something

Comment: @Markasoftware Is it? Then how to prevent this sir? Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses the default Android Dialog for displaying UI corresponding to the alert, prompt, confirm methods.

The Dialog class has method called setCanceledOnTouchOutside that manages a flag. When the flag is true, tapping outside the dialog means the users cancels the dialog (similar to pressing ESC in desktop browser).

In old versions of Android, this flag was false by default. In newer versions (ICS+ according to this http://tofu0913.blogspot.ro/2012/09/android-dialog-setcanceledontouchoutside.html), the flag is true by default.

If you want to obtain what you tried, you could probably with an overlay and some HTML that simulates the alert.

For whoever wants to test further: http://jsfiddle.net/s7TWH/ (I tested with 2.3 - flag is false and 4.4 - flag is true):

```
$('#bombImg').on('touchstart',function(touchEvent) {
    window.alert("Bomb defused");
    touchEvent.preventDefault();    
});
```

Comment: Sir very useful But Im developing phonegap app with JS and HTML then how could I use this Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); in java class? Can we use it in Javascript?

Comment: I used PhoneGap, too. Nice tool. My answer explains why alert behaves differently on various Android versions and that it depends on Chrome/OS. All you can do is test if Cordova's notification http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert works for you OR implement the HTML-based  overlay I mentioned before.

Comment: HTML-based overlay means Popup and somethings else like frame ?? please check my edited question

Comment: I'm not Android developer so I can't help with that, but by HTML overlay I meant something like this: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ Check out the the last example. It's basically HTML with some CSS and javascript to control when it shows/hides.

Comment: Yes sir thanku.. But there might be bug in android with alert box

Comment: If you are referring to the fact that it closes when user taps outside it, then it's not a bug. By design it is suppose to do that in newer Androids (similar to how pressing ESC in desktop browser closes the alert).

Comment: Ya it should not close in all versions of android BUT its closing in higher versions only.. Tried with all possibilities BUT NO luck